# Is it possible & efficient to put a LinearView and ExpandableListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I'm making a GUI with two different parts. The first part (at the top) is composed of some banners, several fixed buttons. So I think using LinearLayout is the most straightforward way to implement. The second part is composed of several similar items grouped together which can be implemented by using ExpandableListView, I think.
However the problem is that the content exceeds the screen size. So I intend to put two of them into a ScrollView. I checked several sources, it seems that putting "ExpandableListView" inside a ScroolView is NOT possible, or not efficent, so I'm afraid...

1. Would you help to confirm if this is possible? efficient ?
2. If no, would you give me some recommendations for this layout design?

I'm indeed looking forward to your supports.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fixed header at the top of a list, use [ListView's header view feature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29).

Putting ListViews in ScrollViews fundamentally makes no sense and here is why:

ListView has one purpose: to efficiently display unbounded data sets. Since these can be extremely large (tens of thousands of items and more) you do not want to create a View for each item up front. Instead, ListView asks its Adapter for Views only for the items that currently fit in the ListView's measured space on screen. When an item's View is scrolled out of sight, ListView disconnects that View and hands it back to the adapter to fill out with new data and reuse to show other items. (This is the `convertView` parameter to an Adapter's `getView` method.)

ScrollView also has one purpose: to take a single child view and give it "infinite" vertical space to fit within. The user can then scroll up and down to see the full content.

Now given this, how many item Views would a ListView create for a 100,000 item Adapter if it had infinite height available to fill? :)

By putting a ListView inside a ScrollView you defeat ListView's key purpose. The parent ScrollView will give the ListView effectively infinite height to work with, but ListView wants to have a bounded height so that it can provide a limited window into a large data set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think I need to follow your way, using Header and Footer. Howerver, I'm still investigating how to add a click listener to a header/footer. Would you mind to give some recommendations or further instructions besides Android Developer page ? I'm a beginner.

Comment: You might find this talk from Google I/O 2010 useful: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html ListView builds on the same principles as the rest of the Android UI toolkit, you might find it helpful to go through some of the other samples and tutorials on the Android Developer site for added context.

Comment: I think i got the point now. Thanks so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Well Expandable List View itself has scrollable property by placing it in scroll view is really undesirable.As the both scroll would contradict and smooth scrolling can't be obtained in that case..

If we have any data to be shown prior or later to list...

Best way is to use header and footer view to list...

I recommend you use header and footer in your case.